# Which radionuclides do not emit gamma rays?

Tags: radioactivity, gamma-rays

Radionuclides that do not emit gamma rays are useful for radioluminescent materials and nuclear batteries because they don't require gamma ray shielding. Most radionuclides seem to emit gamma rays in some of their decay paths, but a few don't. So far I have only been able to find prometheum-147 and tritium which are used in these applications, but there must be other such radionuclides, right? So which are they?

This sounds like a question that should be easily answered with some google searches, but so far I've not been able to find anything except the tritium and promethium isotopes.

*edit:* To clarify, the question is about the entire decay chain of isotopes. I want to know first of all about isotopes that theoretically emit no gammas in their decay chain, but as I'm not sure if those exist at all, I would also like to know about isotopes where the gamma emissions are very low, i.e. where they are insignificant for applications like radioluminescense and nuclear batteries. (I admit this is criterion is a bit fuzzy, but the acceptable gamma levels would be dependent on the application, so there is no single limit available here.)

In addition, to be practical for applications, the isotopes should not be too short lived while also releasing enough energy, so they should have half lives roughly between several months and 1000 years.

Comment: Polonium-210 is a known case for an alpha emitter. That is why the Russians used it to poison Litvinenko.

Comment: Consider that free neutron decay emits a $\gamma$ with a probability of around 1 in a thousand, and Wikipedia says that also happens with the decay of bound neutrons, but I guess the probability of it happening with a low-energy $\beta$ emitter like tritium to be extremely small, and if it does happen the photon may be harmless due to its low energy.

Comment: @Pieter Polonium-210 has a $10^{-5}$ branch to $\alpha + \gamma$, a fact that I exploited for calibration when I built [a Po-210/C-13 source for KamLAND](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:0711.3624). Now, that's a low enough branching ratio that a lethal dose of the stuff doesn't set a survey meter off in a rapidly identifiable way, but I would take issue with a claim that the isotope doesn't emit gamma rays.

Comment: Are you asking which ones for which, following beta decay of their ground states, their daughter doesn't emit gammas? Many isotopes, especially odd-odd ones, can be produced in a variety of long-lived states, not just the ground state. In some cases, we don't even know which state is the ground state.

Comment: Since the question is prefaced with some stuff about applications, I assume the OP really wants to know some isotopes that emit less than some percentage of their energy as gammas -- maybe 1% or something. It's likely to be extremely rare to have isotopes that decay but *never* have a gamma branch. Checking on Loong's list, the first couple I checked both did have gamma branches.

Comment: @BenCrowell My question is about the full decay chain of elements. When I asked the question I was thinking about element that don't have *any* gamma emitting branches in their entire decay chain, but if those don't exist I'll have to settle for elements that emit only very little gamma.

Comment: @JanKanis: You still haven't explained whether you want a list that includes very weak gamma emission. Loong's new answer contains a whole bunch of heavy isotopes that emit alphas. None of these can have zero probability of emitting gammas, because the Q values are big and the density of states in the daughter nucleus is high, so there are guaranteed to be excited states available for the decay. These branches may be weak, possibly too weak to have been detected, but they have to exist, because that's how quantum mechanics works. Any process not prohibited by a conservation law will go.

Comment: @BenCrowell I updated the question. I'm wondering, do low mass alpha/beta emitters also always theoretically emit gamma rays? Does tritium?

Answer (score 4):

The 46 relevant individual (i.e. without considering any daughter nuclides) radionuclides that do not emit any gamma radiation are as follows. Values for the half-lives are taken from ICRP, 2008. Nuclear Decay Data for Dosimetric Calculations. ICRP Publication 107. Ann. ICRP 38 (3).

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
\hline
\text{Nuclide} & \text{Half-life} & \text{Decay mode} \\
\hline
\text{H-3} & 12.32\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Be-10} & 1.51\times10^6\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{C-14} & 5.70\times10^3\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Si-32} & 132\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{P-32} & 14.263\ \mathrm d & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{P-33} & 25.34\ \mathrm d & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{S-35} & 87.51\ \mathrm d & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Ar-39} & 269\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Ar-42} & 32.9\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Fe-60} & 1.5\times10^6\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Ni-63} & 100.1\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Ni-66} & 54.6\ \mathrm h & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Se-79} & 2.95\times10^5\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Rb-87} & 4.923\times10^{10}\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Sr-90} & 28.79\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Zr-93} & 1.53\times10^6\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Ru-106} & 373.59\ \mathrm d & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Pd-107} & 6.5\times10^6\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Cd-113} & 7.7\times10^{15}\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Cd-118} & 50.3\ \mathrm{min} & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{In-115} & 4.41\times10^{14}\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Sn-121} & 27.03\ \mathrm h & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Cs-135} & 2.3\times10^6\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Nd-144} & 2.29\times10^{15}\ \mathrm a & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Sm-146} & 1.03\times10^8\ \mathrm a & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Sm-147} & 1.060\times10^{11}\ \mathrm a & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Sm-148} & 7\times10^{15}\ \mathrm a & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Gd-148} & 74.6\ \mathrm a & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Gd-150} & 1.79\times10^6\ \mathrm a & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Gd-152} & 1.08\times10^{14}\ \mathrm a & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Dy-154} & 3.0\times10^6\ \mathrm a & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Hf-174} & 2.0\times10^{15}\ \mathrm a & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Re-187} & 4.12\times10^{10}\ \mathrm a & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Os-186} & 2.0\times10^{15}\ \mathrm a & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Pt-190} & 6.50\times10^{11}\ \mathrm a & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Pt-202} & 44\ \mathrm h & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Pb-209} & 3.253\ \mathrm h & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Bi-212n} & 7.0\ \mathrm{min} & \text{beta minus} \\
\text{Po-212} & 2.99\times10^{-7}\ \mathrm s & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Po-218} & 3.10\ \mathrm{min} & \text{alpha/beta minus} \\
\text{At-218} & 1.5\ \mathrm s & \text{alpha/beta minus} \\
\text{At-219} & 56\ \mathrm s & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Rn-215} & 2.30\ \mathrm{µs} & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Rn-216} & 4.5\times10^{-5}\ \mathrm s & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Rn-217} & 5.40\times10^{-4}\ \mathrm s & \text{alpha} \\
\text{Cf-255} & 85\ \mathrm{min} & \text{beta minus} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

---

Meanwhile, OP has clarified in a [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/398076/which-radionuclides-do-not-emit-gamma-rays/525789#comment1188267_398076) that the question is not about only individual radionuclides (i.e. without daughter nuclides) that emit any radionuclides. The actual question is about radionuclides that do not emit any gamma radiation in their entire decay chain (i.e. including daughter nuclides).

> My question is about the full decay chain of elements. When I asked the question I was thinking about element that don't have any gamma emitting branches in their entire decay chain,

In this case, the list is reduced to 31 radionuclides as follows.

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
\hline
\text{Nuclide} & \text{Half-life} & \text{Decay chain} \\
\hline
\text{H-3} & 12.32\ \mathrm a & \text{He-3} \\
\text{Be-10} & 1.51\times10^6\ \mathrm a & \text{B-10} \\
\text{C-14} & 5.70\times10^3\ \mathrm a & \text{N-14} \\
\text{Si-32} & 132\ \mathrm a & \text{P-32, S-32} \\
\text{P-32} & 14.263\ \mathrm d & \text{S-32} \\
\text{P-33} & 25.34\ \mathrm d & \text{S-33} \\
\text{S-35} & 87.51\ \mathrm d & \text{Cl-35} \\
\text{Ar-39} & 269\ \mathrm a & \text{K-39} \\
\text{Ni-63} & 100.1\ \mathrm a & \text{Cu-63} \\
\text{Se-79} & 2.95\times10^5\ \mathrm a & \text{Br-79} \\
\text{Rb-87} & 4.923\times10^{10}\ \mathrm a & \text{Sr-87} \\
\text{Pd-107} & 6.5\times10^6\ \mathrm a & \text{Ag-107} \\
\text{Cd-113} & 7.7\times10^{15}\ \mathrm a & \text{In-113} \\
\text{In-115} & 4.41\times10^{14}\ \mathrm a & \text{Sn-115} \\
\text{Sn-121} & 27.03\ \mathrm h & \text{Sb-121} \\
\text{Cs-135} & 2.3\times10^6\ \mathrm a & \text{Ba-135} \\
\text{Nd-144} & 2.29\times10^{15}\ \mathrm a & \text{Ce-140} \\
\text{Sm-146} & 1.03\times10^8\ \mathrm a & \text{Nd-142} \\
\text{Sm-147} & 1.060\times10^{11}\ \mathrm a & \text{Nd-143} \\
\text{Sm-148} & 7\times10^{15}\ \mathrm a & \text{Nd-144, Ce-140} \\
\text{Gd-148} & 74.6\ \mathrm a & \text{Sm-144} \\
\text{Gd-150} & 1.79\times10^6\ \mathrm a & \text{Sm-146, Nd-142} \\
\text{Gd-152} & 1.08\times10^{14}\ \mathrm a & \text{Sm-148, Nd-144, Ce-140} \\
\text{Dy-154} & 3.0\times10^6\ \mathrm a & \text{Gd-150, Sm-146, Nd-142} \\
\text{Hf-174} & 2.0\times10^{15}\ \mathrm a & \text{Yb-170} \\
\text{Re-187} & 4.12\times10^{10}\ \mathrm a & \text{Os-187} \\
\text{Os-186} & 2.0\times10^{15}\ \mathrm a & \text{W-182} \\
\text{Pt-190} & 6.50\times10^{11}\ \mathrm a & \text{Os-186, W-182} \\
\text{Pb-209} & 3.253\ \mathrm h & \text{Bi-209} \\
\text{Po-212} & 2.99\times10^{-7}\ \mathrm s & \text{Pb-208} \\
\text{Rn-216} & 4.5\times10^{-5}\ \mathrm s & \text{Po-212, Pb-208} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Not sure why my earlier comments were deleted. This still doesn't seem right. For example, 174Hf decays to 170Yb by alpha decay, with a Q value of 2493 keV. That means there is guaranteed to be some probability of decay to various low-lying excited states in 170Yb. The probability may be small, but there's no way it's zero. That's not possible because of the way quantum mechanics works.

Comment: Shouldn't Pm-147 be in this list too? According to wikipedia it does not emit gammas, which is why it is used in radioluminescent paint.

Comment: @JanKanis I only list radionuclides that have no gamma lines in the ICRP 107 data file (which is used in radiation protection). Pm-147 has three gamma lines (although with very low emission probabilities): _E_ = 76.073 keV (_P_ = 1.16850E-10), _E_ = 121.220 keV (_P_ = 2.85E-05), and _E_ = 197.299 keV (_P_ = 3.42E-09). That’s only 3.455E-06 MeV per nuclear transformation, which is virtually nothing for practical radiation protection purposes. By way of comparison, Co-60 has 2.504E+00 MeV per nuclear transformation.